# c++ no matching function for call to base-class method from derived-class

Tags: c++, derived-class, base-class, pointer-to-member

I got a little confused as gcc dropped an error with the message

```
error: no matching function for call to ...
note: candidates are ...
```

So I did a wrong function call as it seems to be. Here is what I really got from gcc:

```
src/Services/UserService/UserService.cpp:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘Services::UserService::UserService::registerMethod(const char [6], Services::UserService::Request::LoginRequest* (Services::UserService::UserService::*)(std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Lib::request::Param, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Lib::request::Param> > >&))’
src/Services/UserService/../../Lib/Service/Service.hpp:47: note: candidates are: void Lib::service::Service::registerMethod(std::string, Lib::request::Request* (Lib::service::Service::*)(std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Lib::request::Param, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Lib::request::Param> > >&))
```

I got a base class **Lib::service::Service** that is derived by **Services::UserService::UserService**.
And I did another base class **Lib::request::Request** which is derived by **Services::UserService::Request::LoginRequest**

The base class Lib::service::Service implements a method called "registerMethod", which takes a string and a function pointer.

```
typedef Lib::request::Request* (Lib::service::Service::*FuncPtr)(map<string, Param>&);

...

void registerMethod(string MethodName, FuncPtr Func);
```

So, formatting the gcc outbut a bit gives me this:

Requested is:

```
Services::UserService::UserService::registerMethod(
    const char [6], 

    Services::UserService::Request::LoginRequest* (
        Services::UserService::UserService::*
    )(
        std::map<
            std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, 
            Lib::request::Param, 
            std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, 
            std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Lib::request::Param> > 
        >&
    )
)
```

And gcc says, that a (and the only one - and that one I want to be used) candidate is:

```
void 
Lib::service::Service::registerMethod(
    std::string, 

    Lib::request::Request* (
        Lib::service::Service::*
    )(
        std::map<
            std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, 
            Lib::request::Param, 
            std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, 
            std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Lib::request::Param> > 
        >&
    )
)
```

So, as Services::UserService::UserService is derived from Lib::service::Service
and Serices::UserService::Request::LoginRequest is derived from Lib::request::Request I thought this is working as I defined the function to match the base classes and therefore could use them with the derived classes too.

Where am I wrong here? If this helps, here is some more code ;-)

**Thanks so far!**

Best regards,

Sebastian

---

```
namespace Lib {
    namespace service {
        class Service;
    }
}

namespace Lib {
    namespace request {

        class Request {
        public:
            Request(Lib::service::Service *Owner);
            virtual ~Request();

            virtual void Execute() = 0;

            void join(Lib::Session::Session *session);

        protected:
            Lib::service::Service *module;
            Lib::Session::Session *session;
            map<string, Param> params;

        private:
        };
    }
}

typedef Lib::request::Request* (Lib::service::Service::*FuncPtr)(map<string, Param>&);

namespace Lib {
    namespace service {

        class Service {
        public:
            const string Name;

            Service();
            virtual ~Service();

            Request* Call(string MethodName, map<string, Param> &Params);

        protected:
            void registerMethod(string MethodName, FuncPtr Func);

        private:
            map<string, FuncPtr> methods;
        };
    }
}
```

-

```
namespace Lib
{
    namespace service
    {

        Service::Service()
        {
        }

        Service::~Service()
        {
        }

        void Service::registerMethod(string MethodName, FuncPtr Func)
        {
            this->methods.insert(pair<string, FuncPtr>(MethodName, Func));
        }

        Request* Service::Call(string MethodName, map<string, Param> &Params)
        {
            FuncPtr Func;

            Func = this->methods[MethodName];
            Request *req = (*this.*Func)( Params );

            return req;
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
namespace Services {
    namespace UserService {

        class UserService : public Lib::service::Service {
        public:
            const string Name;

            UserService();
            virtual ~UserService();

            LoginRequest* Login(map<string, Param> &params);
            LogoutRequest* Logout(map<string, Param> &params);
        private:

        };
    }
}
```

-

```
namespace Services
{
    namespace UserService
    {

        UserService::UserService() : Name("UserModule")
        {
            this->registerMethod("Login", &UserService::Login);
            this->registerMethod("Logout", &UserService::Logout);
        }

        UserService::~UserService()
        {
        }

        LoginRequest* UserService::Login(map<string, Param> &params)
        {
            LoginRequest *request = new LoginRequest(this);

            //...

            return request;
        }

        LogoutRequest* UserService::Logout(map<string, Param> &params)
        {
            LogoutRequest *request = new LogoutRequest(this);

            //...

            return request;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That is just too much of code. Can you not create a small example self compilable example which demonstrates your problem? Chances are you will find the root cause of the problem yourself by the time you are done with a small example.

Comment: I'm not going to wade through all that code. The error message tells you what's wrong. The part marked "no matching call..." tells you what the calling code is doing. The part marked "candidates are ..." tells you which overloads it looked at. It couldn't choose between them.

Comment: @PeteBecker: This is the problem with the so called reputation points of SO. Poor questions with lack of any effort will still get answered.Wish there was a freeze meter on every Q. The Q could not be answered unless it fits in some basic criteria(*effort or clarity*).Unless the questioner modify's it enough to make the basic criteria the Q cannot be answered & gets unfrozen for answering once it is done.

Comment: I don't see that I did bring less effort to this. I already posted there my thoughts, most of you did not read this as you were repeating what I wrote at my initial post. I appended the important parts of the code as I saw in many questions, that there were not enough code posted to be able to clearly answer the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally solved it by myself, thanks for every contributor. No thanks to those people who did not read my Q and thought they have to judge about my effort.

However, if someone else run into this:

It was quite as I wrote in my initial post, the call was wrong. To work, there is a need to do a reinterpret_cast to the target function pointer. This works for the derived classes.

```
this->registerMethod("Login", reinterpret_cast<FuncPtr>(&UserService::Login));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forget to put a `void` in declaring body of the method. You have below code, declaring the method in class:

```
void registerMethod(string MethodName, FuncPtr Func);
```

Then you must put `void` in declaring the body.

```
void Services::UserService::UserService::registerMethod( ...
^^^^
```

Comment: The method is never beeing overloaded. It calls ( and should do so! ) the base class method which has the void in front -
  void Service::registerMethod(string MethodName, FuncPtr Func) { ... } - I put that class definition to the main post, to clarify this